# Auto download link issue while jquery dialog visible

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a download function to invoke file download in another tab as follow

```
function download(url) {
    var id ='dl_'+(Math.random()+'').split('.')[1];
    $('a.download_links').remove();
    $("<a class='download_links' >Download Link</a>")
        .hide()
        .attr("href", url)
        .attr("id",id)
        .attr("target",'_blank')
        .appendTo("body");
    //$('#'+id).click();//does not work either 
    document.getElementById(id).click();
}
```

This does not work when jquery dialog is visible .

Comment: you mean dialouge like alert()?

Comment: I have  jquery modal dialog to generate pdf , which then invokes `download()` function on close event

Comment: We understand it does not work for you, but it would be more helpful for us to get the example and specific error details to help you. can you try using alert() in your function and check if it is getting invoked with your call.

Comment: @Murtaza , thanks Its invokable when dialog get closed . I am able to invoke the download from console

Comment: can you create a small example on jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
var dl = window.open('http://download.url/', '_blank');
```

Comment: is this cross-browser compatible ?